# Run PAM script only when logging in using su

Tags: linux, pam

I have a script in `/usr/local/bin` that I reference in `/etc/pam.d/su` using:

```
session  optional  pam_exec.so  stdout  /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

It runs as expected when I login to `user` from `root` using `su - user`, but it also executes when I `exit` or `logout` from `user`. How do I stop it from running when logging out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @A.B's answer, I added the following lines at the beginning of the script to get what I wanted:

```
if [[ $PAM_TYPE == "close_session" ]]; then  
   exit 0  
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

From the manual [`pam_exec(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_exec.8.html):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> pam_exec is a PAM module that can be used to run an external command.
>
> The child's environment is set to the current PAM environment list, as
> returned by pam_getenvlist(3) In addition, **the following PAM items
> are exported as environment variables**: `PAM_RHOST`, `PAM_RUSER`,
> `PAM_SERVICE`, `PAM_TTY`, `PAM_USER` and **`PAM_TYPE`**, which
> contains one of the module types: `account`, `auth`, `password`,
> `open_session` **and `close_session`**.
>
> [...]

Just have the script check that the environment variable `PAM_TYPE` has not the value `close_session` or else exit.

Comment: thank you. i finally figured it out.